# Minted: customise listing name?

Tags: listings, minted, naming

How do I customize listing name: `Listing 1:` thing -- when I use minted? Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
% \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Something} % doesn't work!

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{minted}{python}
for i in range(3):
    print i
\end{minted}

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Page 7 of the `minted` documentation: `\renewcommand\listingscaption{Program code}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are talking about the `listing` environment from `minted` package and a `\caption` there:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
    \renewcommand\listingscaption{My Listing Caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{listing}[H]
        \begin{minted}[gobble=12]{python}
            for i in range(3):
                print i
        \end{minted}
        \caption{Example of a listing.}
        \label{lst:example}
    \end{listing}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]