# Modify space before and after minted text

Tags: line-spacing, minted

I have to write an article with many blocks embedding equations and the output from R.
I've decided to use the package *minted* for everything as the best option to avoid complex formating.

I've also defined general spacing and font sizes.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, spanish]{article}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.4cm, top=4.7cm, bottom=4.1cm]{geometry} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.54}
\usepackage{parskip}   % separación entre parrafos
\parskip=12pt
\setlength{\parindent}{2em} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.92,0.97,1}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small, bgcolor=bg]{text}
    E=m·c^2
    some code
\end{minted}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small, bgcolor=bg, escapeinside=||, mathescape=true]{text}
    |$E=m·c^2$|
\end{minted}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

It seems OK, but 
how can I change the line spacing before and after the minted text? 
I would like to have two kind of minted text on my article, one like it is now, independent paragraphs, but another kind with simple spacingtimgur.

How can I get in my example simple line spacing, as if it was all the same paragraph?

Something like this:
[image]

I need to write many equations and small minted code but I don't want to waste much space.

I prefer a simple solution, sort of command to remove previous space instead of large macro definitions.

I would also like to know how to keep the previous text and the minted block together on the same page if there is a pagebreak. Otherwise latex mixes large tables and figures and is difficult to keep track of things.

PS: I have created a new related question:
[How to reduce the space before and after minted text with captions (listing)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507789/how-to-reduce-the-space-before-and-after-minted-text-with-captions-listing)
where I'm asking how to reduce the margins when using captions, within a listing environment.

Comment: You set `\parskip` to 12pt, `\parindent` to 2em and `\baselinestretch` to 1.54? Isn't it too much? I can understand you need “doublespacing”, but then why adding a nonzero parskip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `\parskip` after a `minted` environment, with the help of `etoolbox`.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.4cm, top=4.7cm, bottom=4.1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[skip=12pt,indent=2em]{parskip}   % separación entre parrafos
%\usepackage{indentfirst} % babel-spanish does it
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.92,0.97,1}
\setstretch{1.54}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\TextOrMath{\textperiodcentered}{\cdot}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small, bgcolor=bg]{text}
    E=m·c^2
    some code
\end{minted}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small, bgcolor=bg, escapeinside=||, mathescape=true]{text}
    |$E=m·c^2$|
\end{minted}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

I have added some improvements to your code.

[image]

However, a large `\parskip` along with double spacing *and* indentation is really too much. If you're forced to use double spacing, at least don't set the parskip.

With your setting with `polyglossia`, here's the code.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.4cm, top=4.7cm, bottom=4.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[skip=12pt,indent=2em]{parskip}   % separación entre parrafos
%\usepackage{indentfirst} % polyglossia does it
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.92,0.97,1}
\setstretch{1.54}

%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\TextOrMath{\textperiodcentered}{\cdot}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small, bgcolor=bg]{text}
    E=m·c^2
    some code
\end{minted}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small, bgcolor=bg, escapeinside=||, mathescape=true]{text}
    |$E=m·c^2$|
\end{minted}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not using babel because I use polyglossia instead, though I haven't included all my preamble.

Comment: Why doesn't it work by just using "~" before?

Comment: And \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\TextOrMath{\textperiodcentered}{\cdot}} doesn't work for me: "undefined control sequence". Maybe because I'm not using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} but LuaTex and fontspec

Comment: @skan I added the changes for the setting.

Comment: have you just removed the \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\TextOrMath{\textperiodcentered}{\cdot}} line? Do I need it?

Comment: @skan You don't need the line with XeLateX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The solution is good but I would also like to use a caption and label. The solution is to embed the minted block within a listing https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107516/minted-customise-listing-name
But then I get very large blank space before and after.
How can I reduce this margins to the minimum and use a caption?

Comment: @skan That's a completely different matter.

Comment: OK, I have opened a new question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507789/how-to-reduce-the-space-before-and-after-minted-text-with-captions-listing